# How to modify Powerpoint Chart ChartData by Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint

I´m trying to modify ChartData (values) in Powerpoint by using Excel-VBA.
The ChartData is not linked to the other Excel Workbook.

Checks:
- PowerPoint is open
- required Presentation is open
- The Chart is on Slide 4

Behavior:
- Chart Title Changes 
- Workbook with ChartData opens 
- Runtime Error '424' : Objeckt Required
- Debugging marks the following line:

```
Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("B2:B5").Value = 50
```

Hope somebody can help me out... :-)

```
Sub ModifyChartData()

Dim pptApp As Object
Dim pptPres As Presentation

Set pptApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
Set pptPres = pptApp.ActivePresentation


pptPres.Slides(4).Shapes("Diagramm1").Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Sales Overview"
pptPres.Slides(4).Shapes("Diagramm1").Chart.ChartData.Activate
Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("B2:B5").Value = 50
Workbooks.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

[image]

Code:

```
Set pptApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
Set pptPres = pptApp.ActivePresentation
pptPres.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Sales Overview"
pptPres.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart.ChartData.Activate
pptPres.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets("Blad1").Range("B2:B5").Value = 50
```

Result:

[image]